# Comparing two files and print empty line for unmatched?

Tags: text-processing, awk

I'm trying to match two files and print the match result and leave empty line for unmatch result, based on the Number column 3. The idea here to make the two file length the same .

example: file 1

```
BMW 111  N1
BENZ 123 N2
TOYOTA 122 N3
```

file2

```
N1
N23
N3
```

result:

```
BMW 111 N1
*blank line (N23 does not exit in file 1*
TOYOTA 122 N3
```

I used AWK to match the two file but I'm not able to insert *blank line*

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}$3 in a{print $1,$2,$3}' file2.txt file1.txt > result.txt
```

as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977408/how-do-i-insert-a-blank-line-every-n-lines-using-awk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for line in $(cat file2); 
do
   grep $line file1 || echo ""; 
done
```

Produces the following output

```
$ for line in $(cat file2); do   grep $line file1 || echo ""; done
BMW 111  N1

TOYOTA 122 N3
$
```

Comment: Will not work as intended if matching data are on different lines.

Comment: @DopeGhoti Not true. The grep searches the entire file and picks the line that matches.

Comment: Actually, I did need to fix the logic however. `&&` needed to be `||`

Comment: Try it again with `N3` on the first line and `N1` on the last line in one file; you will still see "matches".

Comment: But does not limit the matches to column 3. You can get false positives

Comment: Thanks. work perfectly without any false positive.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `$3 in a{print $1,$2,$3}`, try `!($3 in a){$0 = ""} 1`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming both files are sorted on the join field:

```
$ join -1 3 -a 2 -o1.1,1.3,1.3 file1 file2
BMW N1 N1

TOYOTA N3 N3
```

This does a relational JOIN operation on the two files, using the third column of `file1` (with `-1 3`) and the first and only column of `file2`.  We ask for all lines of `file2` to be included in the output (with `-a 2`), even unpaired lines.  For the output, we ask for all three fields of the first file to be printed (with the `-o` flag). Empty fields on unmatched lines will remain empty, but one could add `-e something` to fill them in with the string `something`.

If the two file are *not* sorted on the join field, you may pre-sort them using

```
sort -k3 -o file1 file1
sort -o file2 file2
```

or, you may do the sorting at the same time as the join, if your shell supports process substitutions, with

```
join -1 3 -a 2 -o1.1,1.3,1.3 \
    <( sort -k3 file1 ) \
    <( sort file2 )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  paste file1.txt file2.txt | sed -Ee 's/\s(\S+)\s+\1\s*$/ \1/;t'  -e g
```

This prints the contents of the files side by side per line basis and then we let Gnu sed operate on this line.

In case the last fields of files match, we erase that from the line and print it.
Otherwise, we print an empty line, retrieved from the empty hold space.

Another way could be :

```
paste a.txt b.txt | awk '{NF -= $(NF) == $(NF-1) ? 1 : NF}1'
```